# Problem with PWM, running DC motor using L298 H bridge(using RPi.GPIO python module)

Tags: pwm

[image: Two Motors without PWM]
This picture shows the code i am using to run back and forth a dc motor for specified time and it works well, no problem with this.!

Problem is here, as soon as i switch on my Pi and try to run the pwm code  motor doesnt run, but when i run the code in 1st picture and then run the pwm code it runs fine... whats happening here??? Am i missing something?? Did i not activate some Pin or something like that??
    **pwm code**

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO ## Import GPIO library
import time ## Import 'time' library. Allows us to use 'sleep'

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) ## Use board pin numbering
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT) ## Setup GPIO Pin 11(motor b enable) to OUT
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT)  ## Setup GPIO Pin 11(motor a enable) to OUT
GPIO.setup(13, GPIO.OUT) ## Setup GPIO Pin 11(motor a control) to OUT
GPIO.setup(15, GPIO.OUT)  ## Setup GPIO Pin 11(motor a control) to OUT
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.OUT)   ## Setup GPIO Pin 11(motor b control) to OUT
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)    ## Setup GPIO Pin 11(motor b control) to OUT
GPIO.output(7, False)        ## disable motor a
GPIO.output(11, True)          ## enable motor b
p=GPIO.PWM(11,50)          ## frequency 50
p.start(1)
try:
    while True:
           GPIO.output(13, False)   ## dont run motor a
           GPIO.output(15, False)      ## dont run motor a
           GPIO.output(16, True)        ##  run motor b
           GPIO.output(18, False)         ##  run motor b
           p.ChangeDutyCycle(10)     ## duty cycle 10%
except KeyboardInterrupt:
     pass
p.stop()
gpio.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 2):

I think `GPIO.setup(18, False)` should be `GPIO.output(18, False)`

PS 10% duty cycle might not be enough to set the motor into motion.

Comment: sorry i entered a mistake, i corrected it now...but why is it running(at 10%) after running first code.....its not working only if try to run the code before running the first

Comment: @RuthvikVaila Why not see if 90% works?  10% may be enough to keep the motor running once started but not enough to run from a cold start,